# Chrome for loop optimization

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, for-loop, foreach

So I was curious what would be faster for iterating through an array, the normal `for` loop or `forEach` so I executed this code in the console:

```
var arr = [];
arr.length = 10000000;
//arr.fill(1);
for (var i_1 = 0; i_1 < arr.length; i_1++) {
arr[i_1] = 1;
}
//////////////////////////////////
var t = new Date();
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var a = arr[i];
    if (a & 1) {
        sum += a;
    }
    else {
        sum -= a;
    }
}
console.log(new Date().getTime() - t.getTime());
console.log(sum);

t = new Date();
sum = 0;
arr.forEach(function (value, i, aray) {
    var a = value;
    if (a & 1) {
        sum += a;
    }
    else {
        sum -= a;
    }
});
console.log(new Date().getTime() - t.getTime());
console.log(sum);
```

Now the results in Chrome are 49ms for the `for` loop, 376ms for the `forEach` loop. Which is ok but the results in Firefox and IE (and Edge) are a lot different.

In both other browsers the first loop takes ~15 seconds (yes seconds) while the `forEach` takes "only" ~4 seconds.

My question is can someone tell me the exact reason Chrome is so much faster?

I tried all kinds of operations inside the loops, the results were always in favor for Chrome by a mile.

Comment: You can for sure shave some off by doing `for (var i_1 = 0, n=arr.length; i_1 < n; i_1++) {` - also try jsperf for your tests. Also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what do you mean by "shave off".

Comment: Make it faster. _Shave some time off_

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for the `console.time` hint, but still, I don't want to make it faster but to know why Chrome is so much faster than the other browsers in that case.

Comment: I'd recommend [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) for future speed tests. As for why Chrome is faster, my answer would be **"because V8"**.

Comment: @mplungjan that optimization has been rendered useless a long time ago. In most cases, the browser will recognize when arr won't vary in length and will replace arr.length with a constant anyway

Comment: Ok, wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @chnging do you want to see something interesting? Change this line of code `var sum = 0;` for `let sum = 0;` and post again your numbers

Comment: Building on the suggestion by @DiegoZoracKy, use `let a = arr[i];` in the for loop and see if that slows things down. Because `var` is [function-scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), not block-scoped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not know the specifics of V8 in Chrome or the interpreter of Firefox / Edge, but there are some very general insights. Since V8 compiles Javascript to native code, let's see what it potentially could do:

- Very crudely: variables like your `var i` can be modelled as a very general Javascript variable, so that it can take any type of value from numbers to objects (modelled as a pointer to a `struct Variable` for instance), or the compiler can deduce the actual type (say an `int` in C++ for instance) from your JS and compile it like that. The latter uses less memory, exploits caching, uses less indirection, and can potentially be as fast as a `for`-loop in C++. V8 probably does this.
- The above holds for your array as well: maybe it compiles to a memory efficient array of `int`s stored contiguously in memory; maybe it is an array of pointers to general objects.
- Temporary variables can be removed.
- The second loop could be optimized by inlining the function call, maybe this is done, maybe it isn't.

The point being: all JS interpreters / compilers can potentially exploit these optimizations. This depends on a lot of factors: the trade-off between compilation and execution time, the way JS is written, etc.

V8 seems to optimize a lot, Firefox / Edge maybe don't in this example. Knowing why precisely requires in-depth understanding of the interpreter / compiler.

Comment: Just an interesting note. Change this line of code `var sum = 0;` for `let sum = 0;` and check your numbers. Now refresh everything and then change `var sum = 0;` for `let sum = 0;` and `arr.forEach(` for `arr.find(` and check your numbers again. Testing on `57.0.2987.98 (64-bit)`, these subtle changes will show you how internal optizimations on specific methods and concerning `scope` handling can have a great impact on your process.

Answer (score 1):

For loop is the afastest when compared to other iterators in every browser. But when comparing browsers ie is the slowest in iteration of for loops. Go and try jsperf.com for optimization is going to be my best recommendation. V8 engine implementation is the reason. After chrome split from webkit it stripped off more than 10k line of code in first few days.

Comment: Is not just that simple anymore. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719234/chrome-for-loop-optimization?noredirect=1#comment72997355_42720321

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy I did not understand your point. Can you elaborate? Do you mean to say that for loop is slower?

Comment: with the changes i mentioned, you will see better numbers for the latter array iterator `arr.find()`. Can you try and give a feedback?

Comment: Would it be slower than for loop? Though `.find()` method is not a direct apple to apple for `for` and `forEach` it should still be slower than `for` loop. I have not tested it but considering  `for` loop is the lowest level of iteration it should be faster.

Comment: yes i was thinking the same as you before theses tests that i mentioned. Just by changing to `let sum = 0`,  and keeping `forEach`, you will see the execution time of both to be almost equivalent. `find()` will loop through all the positions in an Array until it finds a match, so if it doesn't find none, it can be used in a hacked way as a `forEach`. With a gain like that in the execution time, it can be a good hack to be used in some cases. On Node.js 6.9.2 the forEach of this example took ~2400ms.

Comment: Yes. The iterations have been optimized for many. But optimization is not a easy job to do and needs a lot of view points and perf testing O(n). Try running a million or 10 million iterations. :-) And if you are unsure of what to do and use, I do recommend use of lowest level api's and work with it. They will always be the fastest in most cases. I follow that as a thumb rule myself.